# Regex does not match url with www

Tags: regex, url

I'm trying to write a regex that can match both following lines:

```
http://ficsgames.org/cgi-bin/show.cgi?ID=364189186;action=save
http://www.ficsgames.org/cgi-bin/show.cgi?ID=364189186;action=save
```

I've got this:

```
http:\/\/(www)?ficsgames\.org\/cgi-bin\/show\.cgi\?ID=[0-9]+;action=save
```

but it doesn't seem to work - http://regex101.com/r/vB2cM3/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a dot `.` inside of your optional group.

```
(www\.)?
```

Comment: this is a silly of me, but it doesn't work either - http://regex101.com/r/vB2cM3/2

Comment: Sure it does. http://regex101.com/r/vB2cM3/3

Comment: oh, I matched only the first occurrence, 2:44 am, time to sleep

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `\.` in your `(www)?`

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the . after www. (which needs to be escaped)
I've updated your regex link here: 
http://regex101.com/r/vB2cM3/4